# Show that the norm of the component of a vector is smaller than the norm of the vector

Tags: normed-spaces

$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}$I want to show that $\norm{e_i v_i} \leq \norm v$.

But applying the triangle inequality yields  $\norm{v}. \leq   \norm{v-e_i v_i}+  \norm{e_i v_i} $which doesn't really help.

Tips appreciated. thanks

Comment: It doesn't follow from the triangle inequality, because it's not true for a general norm.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! You should probably give some more context to the question so people understand what you're trying to do: What are your $e_i,v_i$ and $v$? Are they elements in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or some $\mathbb{R}^n$ or some other vector space?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou is is true in finite dimensions?

Comment: @nathanhleung Not for a general norm, no.